# EventBus send empty class

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

In my android app I use

```
org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
```

1.I create event:

```
public class NotLoginEvent {
}
```

2. In my fragment send this event:

   EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotLoginEvent());
3. And in activity I receive this event:

   ```
       @Subscribe()
       public void onNotLoginEvent(NotLoginEvent notLoginEvent) {
          // do something
       }
   ```

Nice. It's work fine.
But as you can see the class `NotLoginEvent`  is empty. So is it good to send empty class? Maybe has another solution. I wan't to create empty class to send message.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it in the proper way.

```
public static class MyEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

This is from the official documentation, so i think you are doing it well.

Answer (score 1):

> But as you can see the class NotLoginEvent is empty.

It contains no members, but it is not empty. It still represents the event *type*. Without this class you don't know what the event is or how to listen for it. It's not a problem to create a class just for this purpose.

Additionally, you might add some members to this class in the future. It will be easy to do that because the class already exists.